# Resize a ubuntu partion with an EFI between both

Tags: uefi, gparted, resize, reinstall

I have two disks, one with Windows (sdba) and one with a linux partition (sdb). It need to allocate the unllocated memory to the LInux system if possible. I can't make a resize, because EFI is between the both.
In the last case, to reinstall linux can I delete that efi and merge all free memory + EFI + Swap + ext4? Without affecting the windows boot on the other disk, and without affecting the NTSF files on the disk where I have LInux?

My scenarios is on picture:

[image: gparted screenshot]

With the best regards,

Comment: Totally depends on whether Windows used that ESP or one on its drive. Depends on which drive it saw as default when installed. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair